# Area under Curve Limits

Tags: calculus

If S be the area of the region enclosed by $y=e^{-x^{2}}$, y=0, x=0 and x=1.

Then
(A) $S \ge \frac {1}{e}$  (B)  $S \ge 1-\frac {1}{e}$
(C) $S \le \frac {1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{√e})$  (D) $S \le \frac {1}{√2}+\frac{1}{√e}(1-\frac{1}{√2})$

The correct answer is A,B and D it is multiple choice 
I can find B using the concept $e^{-x^{2}}>e^{-x}$ for x $\in$ (0,1) and integrating from 0 to $\frac{1}{e}$ but not able to deduce A and D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A) follows from (B) as $S\ge1-\frac1e>\frac1e$ (this follows from $e>2$)

Don't know about (D) though...

Comment: I understood about A but i need to understand about D

Comment: I got option D by drawing curve and measuring the area of recangle